# Can CoreMotion continue to collect data in the background with iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, core-motion

I've been trying to pull all of the CoreLocation data in the background and have been having trouble. I'm running it with CoreLocation, but every time I put the app into the background, the data stops being collected. I saw a few other posts around this topic, but no definitive answer. Is this possible with the current version of iOS? Is there a limit to what data in CoreMotion can be gathered in the background?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question [may be a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148399/in-ios-11-devicemotion-in-background-stopped-working).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - Yes, I saw that question. In the comments though Nicholas was saying that it is working for him and a few others were saying it is still not working for them. I'm looking for what Nicholas did to get CoreMotion working in the background on iOS11.